# How to design SQL tables to relate a defined template and instance(s) of that template?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, design-patterns

I am designing a workout tracking application.

My plan is to allow users to define Workout templates that include multiple Exercises. There are two exercise types: strength and cardio.

The Workout template would have basic information like its name and description.
The Exercise template piece would have information depending on type.
For strength, its name, muscle_group*,* weight, sets, and reps.
For cardio, it would have name, cardio_type, distance, and duration.

Now once the template is defined, I want the user to then be able to start a workout and finish it by following their defined workout. Whenever this is done, I want to then store an instance of the current template so the user can track their completed workouts, and then also track progression over time.

I think what I currently have is fine, but I am wondering if it could better be designed by breaking up the tables a bit. Specifically when relating to the different types of exercises, since there are different requirements if we need to track weight and reps or distance and duration.

For example, I would like to have predefined Exercises for the user to choose from. Then all the user would need to do is add their weight/reps or distance/duration and then this could be stored as a template for the user. But how can I achieve this?

Here is what I currently have. Like I said, I think it is fine, but I would like to handle the exercises in a better way but am not sure how to.

I also feel like having two sets of many-to-many tables that do almost the same exact type of mapping, but different if its a template or instance.

I apologize if my constraint naming is a bit hard to follow.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_info (
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    first_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

-------------------------
------  Templates  ------
-------------------------

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS workout (
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,  -- Each workout name should be unique
    description TEXT NOT NULL,
    created_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    last_modified_time TIMESTAMP,
    user_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    -- If a user_info row is deleted, this workout will also be deleted
    CONSTRAINT fk_workout_user_info
        FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user_info(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    -- Want each workout to have a unique name per user
    UNIQUE (name, user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS strength_exercise (
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    muscle_group VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,     -- SHOULDERS, CHEST, etc.
    weight INT NOT NULL,                -- Weight in lbs
    sets INT NOT NULL,                  -- # of sets
    reps INT NOT NULL,                  -- # of reps per set
    user_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    -- If a user-info row is deleted, this exercise will also be deleted
    CONSTRAINT fk_weight_exercise_to_user_info
        FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user_info(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    -- Want each strength_exercise to have a unique name per user
    UNIQUE (name, user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cardio_exercise (
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    cardio_type VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,      -- INDOOR RUN, OUTDOOR WALK, POOL SWIM, etc.
    distance DECIMAL NULL,              -- Distance in miles
    duration INT NOT NULL,              -- Duration in seconds
    user_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    -- If a user-info row is deleted, this exercise will also be deleted
    CONSTRAINT fk_cardio_exercise_to_user_info
        FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user_info(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    -- Want each cardio_exercise to have a unique name per user
    UNIQUE (name, user_id)
);

-------------------------
------  Instances  ------
-------------------------

-- Represents that a workout occurred, with how long it took, how it felt, etc.
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS workout_instance (
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    workout_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    start_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    end_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    duration INT NOT NULL,
    feeling VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    notes TEXT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_workout_instance_workout
        FOREIGN KEY (workout_id) REFERENCES workout(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS strength_exercise_instance (
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    exercise_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    weight INT NOT NULL,                -- Weight in lbs
    sets INT NOT NULL,                  -- # of sets
    reps INT NOT NULL,                  -- # of reps per set
    CONSTRAINT fk_strength_exercise_instance_strength_exercise
        FOREIGN KEY (exercise_id) REFERENCES strength_exercise(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cardio_exercise_instance (
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    exercise_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    distance DECIMAL NULL,              -- Distance in miles
    duration INT NOT NULL,              -- Duration in seconds
    CONSTRAINT fk_cardio_exercise_instance_exercise_id
        FOREIGN KEY (exercise_id) REFERENCES cardio_exercise(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

-------------------------
------    Maps    -------
-------------------------

-- Maps strength exercises to workouts as a part of the workout definition
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS strength_exercise_workout (
    exercise_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    workout_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (exercise_id, workout_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_strength_exercise_workout_exercise_id
        FOREIGN KEY (exercise_id) REFERENCES strength_exercise(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_strength_exercise_workout_workout_id
        FOREIGN KEY (workout_id) REFERENCES workout(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

-- Maps cardio exercises to workouts as a part of the workout definition
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cardio_exercise_workout (
    exercise_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    workout_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (exercise_id, workout_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_cardio_exercise_workout_exercise_id
        FOREIGN KEY (exercise_id) REFERENCES cardio_exercise(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_cardio_exercise_workout_workout_id
        FOREIGN KEY (workout_id) REFERENCES workout(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

-- Maps strength exercise instances to workout instances
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS strength_exercise_workout_instance (
    exercise_instance_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    workout_instance_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (exercise_instance_id, workout_instance_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_strength_exercise_workout_instance_exercise_instance_id
        FOREIGN KEY (exercise_instance_id) REFERENCES strength_exercise_instance(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_strength_exercise_workout_instance_workout_instance_id
        FOREIGN KEY (workout_instance_id) REFERENCES workout_instance(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

-- Maps strength exercise instances to workout instances
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cardio_exercise_workout_instance (
    exercise_instance_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    workout_instance_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (exercise_instance_id, workout_instance_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_cardio_exercise_workout_instance_exercise_instance_id
        FOREIGN KEY (exercise_instance_id) REFERENCES cardio_exercise_instance(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_cardio_exercise_workout_instance_workout_instance_id
        FOREIGN KEY (workout_instance_id) REFERENCES workout_instance(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: This should be posted to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead of SO.